# What's the most effective way of storing position information in a database that work well for both lists and grids?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

In our UI, we allow users to store/view items within containers either as lists of items, or as a series of responsive grids.

What is considered best-practice for how the "position" or "index" of each item should be stored in the database?

To be clear, we are currently letting nature take its course by displaying items in order of `last_updated`, but we now want to allow users to re-order items as they see fit.

I've considered both integer and matrix based positioning but I'm not sure which is more future-proof.
I read on a different Stack Exchange question that Atlassian use a string representation instead of integers, but I'm not entirely sure  that's what I'm looking for.

Considerations:

1. What's the ideal data type for the position information?
2. Should nulls be allowed? When might a null happen, and how do we handle it?
3. Should we/How do we prevent two items from occupying the same index?
4. How do we handle updates to positions (E.g. Pushing items down in SQL based on container ID + position being unique as a constraint perhaps?) This is especially puzzling when using string representations of space/ordering as opposed to integers where you can just push everything down by incrementing

*For context, I'm using PostgresQL via Sequelize but welcome solutions from any tech stack.*

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: https://begriffs.com/posts/2018-03-20-user-defined-order.html

Answer (score 1):

Every row gets a `real` column that marks its position. That makes it easy to rearrange rows, because you can always. find a new value between two existing ones.